# Audio on Xubuntu on Zed AirPro laptop is working only via headset but not the speakers

Tags: sound, 20.04, xubuntu

I have a challenge getting linux to work on this notebook, Kali linux & Fedora had no sound at all, Xubuntu atleast works on headset, asking for help to get internal speakers working.

### These are my system specs:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: ZED AIR PRO V1.00.01 
Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic 
Packages: 1888 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1366x768 
WM: Xfwm4 
Theme: Greybird [GTK3] 
Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK3] 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
CPU: Intel Atom Z3735F (4) @ 1.832GHz 
GPU: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display 
Memory: 864MiB / 1926MiB
```

---

### inxi -a

```
 CPU: Quad Core Intel Atom Z3735F (-MCP-) 
 speed/min/max: 500/500/1833 MHz 
 Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 Up: 13m 
 Mem: 888.2/1926.8 MiB (46.1%) 
 Storage: 36.31 GiB (28.7% used) 
 Procs: 192 
 Shell: bash 5.0.17 
 inxi: 3.0.38
```

---

### lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx    
  Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0f)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC  
  Transaction Register
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor 
  Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f) (prog-if 00 [VGA  
  controller])
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series 
  Graphics & Display
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 74
  Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
  Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  I/O ports at 1000 [size=8]
  Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor 
  Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0f) (prog-if 30 
  [XHCI])
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron 
  N2000 Series USB xHCI
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
  Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor 
    Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0f)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series
    Trusted Execution Engine
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 78
    Memory at 90700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at 90600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
    Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor   
   Z36xxx/Z37xxxSeries Power Control Unit (rev 0f)
   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series                 
   Power Control Unit
   Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
   Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
   Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
   Kernel modules: lpc_ich
```

---